# parsing nested functions in python

Tags: python, parsing, nested-function

```
line = "add(multiply(add(2,3),add(4,5)),1)"

def readLine(line):
    countLeftBracket=0
    string = ""
    for char in line:
        if char !=")":
            string += char
        else:
            string +=char
            break

    for i in string:
        if i=="(":
            countLeftBracket+=1

    if countLeftBracket>1:
        cutString(string)
    else:
        return execute(string)

def cutString(string):
    countLeftBracket=0

    for char in string:
        if char!="(":
            string.replace(char,'')
        elif char=="(":
            string.replace(char,'')
            break

    for char in string:
        if char=="(":
            countLeftBracket+=1

    if countLeftBracket>1:
        cutString(string)
    elif countLeftBracket==1:
        return execute(string)

def add(num1,num2):
    return print(num1+num2)

def multiply(num1,num2):
    return print(num1*num2)

readLines(line)
```

I need to execute the whole line string. I tried to cut each function inside of brackets one by one and replace them with the result, but I am kind of lost. Not sure how to continue, my code gets the error:

```
  File "main.py", line 26, in cutString                                                                                 
    if char!="(":                                                                                                       
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Give me an idea of where to move, which method to use?

Comment: What is the expected output? and does `execute` do?

Comment: In general I would suggest starting by writing a lexer that returns a stream of tokens. Parsing by string-substitution is just not the way to approach this.

Comment: @zamir answer to whole nested function. In this case, the answer is 46, but I need to handle more random input in that format.

Comment: @thebjorn can you give me some example, please? I am not really familiar with that.

Comment: I would suggest starting here: https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HowToUsePyparsing.html

Comment: @zamir executing the string like add(2,3), I tried to find result of smaller function and replace them into given string.

Comment: Where is your `execute` function?

Comment: @James inside of the readLine and cutString functions

Comment: If you trust the input, you can create these functions (add, multiply ..) then eval the string containing them.

Comment: @zamir that's what I am trying to do, but not sure how

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like this could be solved with regex.

So this is an example of a single reduction

```
import re, operator
def apply(match):
   func_name = match.group(1) # what's outside the patentesis
   func_args = [int(x) for x in match.group(2).split(',')]
   func = {"add": operator.add, "multiply": operator.mul}
   return str(func[func_name](*func_args))
def single_step(line):
   return re.sub(r"([a-z]+)\(([^()]+)\)",apply,line)
```

For example:

```
line = "add(multiply(add(2,3),add(4,5)),1)"
print(single_step(line))
```

Would output:

> add(multiply(5,9),1)

All that is left to do, is to loop until the expression is a number

```
while not line.isdigit():
   line = single_step(line)
print (line)
```

Will show

> 46

Comment: Copy the entire code from my answer, from top to bottom - it works

Comment: File "main.py", line 3, in apply                                                                                      
    func_name = g[1]                                                                                                    
TypeError: '_sre.SRE_Match' object is not subscriptable

Comment: File "main.py", line 8, in single_step                                                                                
    return re.sub(r"([a-z]+)\(([^()]+)\)",apply,line)                                                                   
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/re.py", line 179, in sub                                                                     
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)

Comment: you're using python2 !

Comment: oh okay let me try on 3.4, sorry

Comment: though you should really mention if you're not using the latest version

Comment: I have a question, how to substitute on the line 5 operand.add to another add function I defined as def add(num1,num2) below that code.

Comment: I just need to define both add and multiply functions myself

Comment: Replace operator.add with the name of your function

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution that uses pyparsing, and as such will be much easier to expand:

```
from pyparsing import *
```

first a convenience function (use the second tag function and print the parse tree to see why)

```
def tag(name):
    """This version converts ["expr", 4] => 4
       comment in the version below to see the original parse tree
    """
    def tagfn(tokens):
        tklist = tokens.asList()
        if name == 'expr' and len(tklist) == 1:
            # LL1 artifact removal
            return tklist
        return tuple([name] + tklist)
    return tagfn

# def tag(name):
#     return lambda tokens: tuple([name] + tokens.asList())
```

Our lexer needs ot recognize left and right parenthesis, integers, and names. This is how you define them with pyparsing:

```
LPAR = Suppress("(")
RPAR = Suppress(")")
integer = Word(nums).setParseAction(lambda s,l,t: [int(t[0])])
name = Word(alphas)
```

our parser has function calls, which take zero or more expressions as parameters. A function call is also an expression, so to deal with the circularity we have to forward declare expr and fncall:

```
expr = Forward()
fncall = Forward()

expr << (integer | fncall).setParseAction(tag('expr'))
fnparams = delimitedList(expr)

fncall << (name + Group(LPAR + Optional(fnparams, default=[]) + RPAR)).setParseAction(tag('fncall'))
```

Now we can parse our string (we can add spaces and more or less than two parameters to functions as well):

```
line = "add(multiply(add(2,3),add(4,5)),1)"
res = fncall.parseString(line)
```

to see what is returned you can print it, this is called the parse-tree (or, since our tag function has simplified it, an abstract syntax tree):

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(list(res))
```

which outputs:

```
[('fncall',
  'add',
  [('fncall',
    'multiply',
    [('fncall', 'add', [2, 3]), ('fncall', 'add', [4, 5])]),
   1])]
```

with the commented out tag function it would be (which is just more work to deal with for no added benefit):

```
[('fncall',
  'add',
  [('expr',
    ('fncall',
     'multiply',
     [('expr', ('fncall', 'add', [('expr', 2), ('expr', 3)])),
      ('expr', ('fncall', 'add', [('expr', 4), ('expr', 5)]))])),
   ('expr', 1)])]
```

Now define the functions that are available to our program:

```
FUNCTIONS = {
    'add': lambda *args: sum(args, 0),
    'multiply': lambda *args: reduce(lambda a, b: a*b, args, 1),
}

# print FUNCTIONS['multiply'](1,2,3,4)   # test that it works ;-)
```

Our parser is now very simple to write:

```
def parse(ast):
    if not ast:  # will not happen in our program, but it's good practice to exit early on no input
        return

    if isinstance(ast, tuple) and ast[0] == 'fncall':
        # ast is here ('fncall', <name-of-function>, [list-of-arguments])
        fn_name = ast[1]          # get the function name
        fn_args = parse(ast[2])   # parse each parameter (see elif below)
        return FUNCTIONS[fn_name](*fn_args)  # find and apply the function to its arguments
    elif isinstance(ast, list):
        # this is called when we hit a parameter list
        return [parse(item) for item in ast]
    elif isinstance(ast, int):
        return ast
```

Now call the parser on the result of the lexing phase:

```
>>> print parse(res[0])  # the outermost item is an expression
46
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a generator function to build a very simple parser:

```
import re, operator
line, f = "add(multiply(add(2,3),add(4,5)),1)", {'add':operator.add, 'multiply':operator.mul}
def parse(d):
   n = next(d, None)
   if n is not None and n != ')':
     if n == '(':
       yield iter(parse(d))
     else:
       yield n
     yield from parse(d)

parsed = parse(iter(re.findall('\(|\)|\w+', line)))
def _eval(d):
   _r = []
   n = next(d, None)
   while n is not None:
      if n.isdigit():
        _r.append(int(n))
      else:
        _r.append(f[n](*_eval(next(d))))
      n = next(d, None)
   return _r

print(_eval(parsed)[0])
```

Output:

```
46
```

Comment: Thanks a lot really appreciate it

Comment: File "main.py", line 4                                                                                                
    if (n:=next(d, None)) is not None and n != ')':                                                                     
         ^                                                                                                              
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Same issue here, @Ajax1234 is assuming you have python 3.8, and you probably have a older version

Comment: @BayramJumageldiyev Yes, my original solution utilized assignment expressions, which are only available in Python 3.8. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: @UriGoren Actually the syntax I was originally using were assignment expressions which are only available in Python 3.8. I edited my solution to be compatible for Python versions <= 3.8